# Pointing a popover at a UITableViewRowAction button

Tags: ios, popover, uitableviewrowaction

I'm trying to launch a popover from one of several `UITableViewRowActions` in a custom `UITableviewCell`. It appears that there are no off the shelf delegate methods available to do this in a straightforward way, but my searches turned up the following approaches to the problem:

[How to get a reference to button from UITableViewRowAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392796/how-to-get-a-reference-to-button-from-uitableviewrowaction)

[How to correctly start a popover segue from a custom uitableviewcell using the storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331292/how-to-correctly-start-a-popover-segue-from-a-custom-uitableviewcell-using-the-s)

[How do I implement the UITapGestureRecognizer into my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355671/how-do-i-implement-the-uitapgesturerecognizer-into-my-application)

[Segue from editActionsForRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318395/segue-from-editactionsforrowatindexpath)

[IOS: verify if a point is inside a rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037710/ios-verify-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rect)

[How to detect a tap gesture in subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459184/how-to-detect-a-tap-gesture-in-subviews)

**While each of these was helpful with some aspect of a workaround, none was comprehensive. However, using some guidance from each, I eventually arrived at this code:**

```
else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AccountPopSegue"])
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;

    CGPoint point = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:_thisCustomCell.contentView];
    UIView *tappedView = [_thisCustomCell hitTest:point withEvent:nil];

    UIViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 186);
    UIPopoverPresentationController *thisPPC = controller.popoverPresentationController;


    thisNavController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    AccountChangeVC *acCVC = (AccountChangeVC *)thisNavController.topViewController;
    acCVC.delegate = self;

    thisPPC.sourceRect = tappedView.bounds;
    thisPPC.sourceView = tappedView.superview;
}
```

**A tap on the the "Acct" action produces the following behavior, shown for three row cases:**

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

**So it appears that I'm close to achieving my desired presentation, but not quite there.**

**Can anyone suggest changes that will make the popover point directly at the launching `UITableViewRowAction` button?**

Comment: maybe you should check that `tappedView.bounds` is the view for `UITableViewRowAction` button

Comment: i believe that `tappedView.bounds` is the bounds for the each of your cell. Therefore, the popover can point to anywhere inside the cell. if you are able to find out the bound for each row action, then you can set the `sourceRect` to that bound

Comment: But there's the rub, Gerald. There doesn't seem to be any known (or at least well-known) means to understand the hierarchy of a cell using `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`. I'm still investigating.

Comment: perhaps you could use action sheet instead. that seem like a common solution

Comment: That would be a possibility. And I may have to do that, my option of choice seemingly impossible to implement. Thanks!